missing packages nss_ldap, nss-pam-ldapd, sssd-ldap, authconfig from yum
I am trying to install these packages on red hat docker image but I see an error (message below is for authconfig, but this is for all the packages listed in the title). yum search also doesn't show these packages.
165.6 No match for argument: authconfig
165.7 Error: Unable to find a match: authconfig

I was wondering if we can get these packages from somewhere and cache them in the build. Did anyone have a similar problem? Can someone please help here?
Thanks!
